# java, extending class with the constructor of main class has parameter

Tags: java

hei. the language is java.
i want to extend this class which the constructor has parameters.

this is the main class

```
public class CAnimatedSprite {
     public CAnimatedSprite(String pFn, int pWidth, int pHeight) {
     }
}
```

this is the child class

```
public class CMainCharacter extends CAnimatedSprite {

    //public void CMainCharacter:CAnimatedSprite(String pFn, int pWidth, int pHeight) {
    //}
}
```

how do i write the correct syntax?
and the error is "constructor cannot be applied to given types"

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can define any arguments you need for your constructor, but it is necessary to call one constructor of the super class as the first line of your own constructor. This can be done using `super()` or `super(arguments)`.

```
public class CMainCharacter extends CAnimatedSprite {

    public CMainCharacter() {
        super("your pFn value here", 0, 0);
        //do whatever you want to do in your constructor here
    }

    public CMainCharacter(String pFn, int pWidth, int pHeight) {
        super(pFn, pWidth, pHeight);
        //do whatever you want to do in your constructor here
    }

}
```

Comment: what if I have multiple constructors in my root class? Do I have to do super() for each of them in my extend class?

Answer (score 4):

The first statement of your constructor must be a call to superclass constructor. The syntax is:

```
super(pFn, pWidth, pHeight);
```

It is up to you to decide, whether you want constructor of your class to have same parameters and just pass them to superclass constructor:

```
public CMainCharacter(String pFn, int pWidth, int pHeight) {
    super(pFn, pWidth, pHeight);
}
```

or pass something else, like:

```
public CMainCharacter() {
    super("", 7, 11);
}
```

And **don't specify return type for constructors**. It's illegal.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CAnimatedSprite {
     public CAnimatedSprite(String pFn, int pWidth, int pHeight) {
     }
}


public class CMainCharacter extends CAnimatedSprite {

    // If you want your second constructor to have the same args
    public CMainCharacter(String pFn, int pWidth, int pHeight) {
        super(pFn, pWidth, pHeight);
    }
}
```