# Java - cannot extend class?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm trying to extend `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` using this code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class FSImage extends BufferedImage {

    public FSImage() {
        // empty constructor
    }
}
```

However, I get some errors:

```
no suitable constructor found for BufferedImage()
constructor java.awt.image.BufferedImage.BufferedImage(java.awt.image.ColorModel, java.awt.image.WritableRaster, boolean, java.util.Hashtable<?,?>) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "empty constructor" implicitly calls the nullary base class constructor, and no such constructor exists in `BufferedImage`. You need to explicitly call the appropriate base class constructor:

```
public FSImage() {
    super(args); // replace "args" with actual arguments to BufferedImage()
    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When extending a class, the subclass must eventually call some constructor of the superclass (whether directly or chaining through other constructors it defines which ultimately call a constructor of the superclass). How you obtain the parameters is often done by implementing a constructor with the same parameters then passing them on with super.

```
BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType)
```

Is one of the constructors to BufferedImage(). Since you are extending it, you could supply this constructor.

```
FSImage(int width, int height, int imageType)
```

Then call super() which calls the constructor of the superclass:

```
FSImage(int width, int height, int imageType) {
  super( width, height, imageType );
}
```

However it should be noted that as long as you call a valid super() constructor, your own constructor need not have the same signature. For example, the following would be a legitimate constructor:

```
FSImage() {
  super( 100, 100, TYPE_INT_RGB );
}
```

If you do not define any constructors the compiler will by default call the no-argument, default constructor of the superclass. Since in this case, it does not exist you must call an existing constructor.

Comment: "When extending a class, you must also implement the constructors that the superclass has." This is plain wrong. Just test it.

Comment: Yes you are right. Correctly, a subclass must eventually call some constructor of the superclass (whether directly or chaining through other constructors it defines which ultimately call a constructor of the superclass). How you obtain the parameters is often done by implementing a constructor with the same parameters then passing them on with super.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedImage` doesn't have an empty constructor.  When extending it, your derived class will need to call a specific constructor in its super class (`BufferedImage`).

Answer (score 1):

There is no default constructor defined in `BufferedImage` so you cannot do

```
new BufferedImage();
```

in a similar fashion, if you create a subclass for `BufferedImage`, it cannot interface with it's super class without satisfying the initialization requirements. So, the sub class constructor must call atleast one of the super class constructor.

you can try this..

```
   public FSImage(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2);

}
```

or

```
public FSImage() {
    super(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `BufferedImage` has not any no argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement one or more of the existing constructors for the class you are extending

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

Comment: No, you don't *override* constructors at all... but each of the constructors you supply must *chain* to a constructor either in the superclass or another in the derived class. (And if you don't supply any constructors, there has to be an accessible parameterless constructor for the compiler-provided one to chain to.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the class you're trying to extend has some required constructor parameters. This similar question has the syntax you will need to use in order to extend the class:

[Java extending class with the constructor of main class has parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056097/java-extending-class-with-the-constructor-of-main-class-has-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

BufferedImage doesn't have a no arg constructor you need to have a super() call inside the constructor with corresponding arguments (that require the size of the image and the type of how it's stored internally)