# Extend my class properly

Tags: java, constructor, extends

I'm using a class Animal. Its constructor takes name as argument.

```
public class Animal {
    String name;
    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Animal cow = new Animal("Cow");
         Humain pierre = new Humain("Pierre", true);
    }
}
```

and a class Human that extends from Animal. Its constructor takes name & a boolean as argument.

```
public class Humain extends Animal{
    boolean isIntelligent;

    public Humain(String name, boolean isIntelligent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isIntelligent = isIntelligent;
    }

}
```

Why do i get this error message in my IDE (netbean) : "Constructor Animal in class Animal cannot be applied to given type" ? I feel like i'm missing something about class extension and constructor.

Comment: You need to invoke `super(name)` in the constructor of `Humain` (you can do it instead of `this.name = name`, since it will have the same effect).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056097/java-extending-class-with-the-constructor-of-main-class-has-parameter

Comment: When you don't call a super constructor explicitly, the no-arg super constructor will be called implicitly (`super();`).

Since there is no constructor with no arguments in your base class you're getting a compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call super in constructor of class Human. Code:

```
public class Humain extends Animal{
    boolean isIntelligent;

    public Humain(String name, boolean isIntelligent) {
        super(name);

        this.isIntelligent = isIntelligent;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a constructor with arguments, when making the constructor with parameters in B, you need to pass in super() a parameter for A

example :

```
class A {
    public A(int x) {   }
  }

  class B extends A {
    public B(int x ) 
    {
       super(x); // need to specify the parameter for class A
       //... 
    }
  }
```

in your case it should be :

```
public Humain(String name, boolean isIntelligent) {
      super(name);

      this.isIntelligent = isIntelligent;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class Humain extends Animal{
  boolean isIntelligent;

  public Humain(String name, boolean isIntelligent) {
      super(name);
      this.isIntelligent = isIntelligent;
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to reassign `this.name`.

Comment: This is wrong, you don't need to do: this.name = name;

Comment: @bercik it's not wrong (since it won't actually change anything), just unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, true, I will edit the answer...

Comment: But why would you do that? For me if something is allowed doesn't mean it's not wrong.