# Implicit super constructor is undefined

Tags: java

I have a basic Java class with the following definition. I have three variables: l,b,h corresponding to length, breadth and height. I am basically trying to access the members of a superclass from a subclass using the super keyword.

```
class dabba {
int l, b, h;

dabba(int l, int b, int h) {
    this.l = l;
    this.b = b;
    this.h = h;
}

void dabbashow() {
        System.out.println("The variables are length:" + l + " breadth:" + b + " height:" + h + ".");
    }
}
```

I have another class which extends the above class.

```
class dabbaweight extends dabba {
int w;

dabbaweight(int l, int b, int h, int w) {
    // super(l, b, h);
    super.l = l;
    super.b = b;
    super.h = h;
    this.w = w;
}

void dabbashow() {
        System.out.println("The variables are length:" + l + " breadth:" + b + " height:" + h + " weight:" + w + ".");
     }

}
```

I provided the main function in a separate class as follows.

```
public class Rando2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dabba mydabba1 = new dabba(1, 2, 3);
        dabbaweight mydabba2 = new dabbaweight(10, 20, 30, 100);
        mydabba1.dabbashow();
        mydabba2.dabbashow();
    }
}
```

And it produces the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Implicit super constructor dabba() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

at dabbaweight.<init>(Rando2.java:17)
at Rando2.main(Rando2.java:33)
```

What is this error? How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Un-comment this - `// super(l, b, h);`

Comment: This question is already solved:
[see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056097/java-extending-class-with-the-constructor-of-main-class-has-parameter)

Comment: @FAlfeo From the hyperinked question, I see that, "The first statement of your constructor must be a call to superclass constructor. "

Comment: @Eran this implies that I cannot initialize the variables of a subclass by using the super keyword ( i.e. super.l = l etc...) ??

Comment: @kiran No. All it implies is that a constructor must call its super class constructor either explicitly or implicitly. when you comment the explicit call `super(l, b, h)`, the compiler inserts `super()` implicitly, but you don't have such a constructor in your super class, so compilation fails.

Comment: @Eran This means that if I have another constructor in the superclass without any parameter, I need not explicitly call the super class constructor and then use the super.l=l, super.b=b, super.h=h to initialize these variables in the subclass ?

Answer (score 1):

If the superclass has not a default constructor (a no-argument constructor), like in your *dabba* class, the relative derived class (subclass) has to explicitly call one of the no-default constructors, so you have to remove the comment to the constructor of the *dabbaweight* class.

```
class dabbaweight extends dabba {
  int w;

  dabbaweight(int l, int b, int h, int w) {
    super(l, b, h);

    this.w = w;
}

  void dabbashow() {
    System.out.println("The variables are length:" + l + " breadth:" + b + " height:" + h + " weight:" + w + ".");
     }
}
```

Comment: If I use 'super(l,b,h)' and then use 'this.w=w', all the variables of 'dabbaweight' are initialized. The use of super (i.e super.l, super.b, super.h)to access the super class variables becomes redundant.

Comment: The meaning of the use of the super constructor  is to correctly initialize the object, it is not to access to his local variables. It is not very clear for me your comment.

Comment: You are right ! I actually was trying to initialize the object's parameters using 'this' keyword. I now understood what I actually had to do. Thanks for taking ur tym on this !

Answer (score 1):

change the following code

```
   dabbaweight(int l, int b, int h, int w) {
       // super(l, b, h);
       super.l = l;
       super.b = b;
       super.h = h;
       this.w = w;
   }
```

to like given below

```
    dabbaweight(int l, int b, int h, int w) {
       super(l, b, h);
       this.w = w;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. But, I want to use the super keyword to access the members of the superclass.