# Overriding methods in the Decorator design pattern (Java)

Tags: java, oop, decorator

I have a question regarding the Decorator design pattern.

I have this class:

```
class SimpleShip<T extends Weapon> implements Comparable<SpaceShip>{

    private T weapon;
    private int points = 100;

    public SimpleShip(T weapon){
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    public int <D extends Weapon> compareTo(SpaceShip<?> other){
        return T.quality - D.quality;
    }

    public void attack(SpaceShip<?> other){
        other.gotHit(T.fire());
    }

    public void gotHit(int reduction){
        this.points -= reduction;
    }
}
```

I want to create two types of spaceship (two added functionalities) - both are different implementations of the gotHit method, I did it the following way:

```
abstract class ShipDecorator<T extends Weapon> extends SimpleShip<T>{

    private SimpleShip<T> simpleShip;

    public ShipDecorator(SimpleShip<T> simpleShip){
        this.simpleShip = simpleShip;
    }

    @Override
    public void attack(SpaceShip<?> other){
        simpleShip.attack();
    }

    @Override
    public int <D extends Weapon> compareTo(SpaceShip<?> other){
        return simpleShip.compareTo(other);
    }

    @Override
    public void gotHit(int reduction){
        simpleShip.gotHit(reduction);
    }
}

class GuardedShip<T extends Weapon> extends ShipDecorator<T>{
    public GuardedShip(SimpleShip<T> other, T weapon){
        super(other);
    }

    @Override
    private void gotHit(int reduction){
        simpleShip.gotHit(reduction);
        Random r = new Random();
        simpleShip.gotHit(r.nextInt(1,25));
    }
}

class SneakyShip<T extends Weapon> extends ShipDecorator<T>{
    public SneakyShip(SimpleShip<T> other, T weapon){
        super(other);
    }

    @Override
    private void gotHit(int reduction){
        if(new Random().nextDouble() > 0.25){
            simpleShip.gotHit(reduction);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is - should all methods in the API of SimpleShip be overriden by a decorator?
I think that they should because you must delegate the requests to the saved SimpleShip instance, but the school solution I was given to this problem doesn't override it and it confuses me.

Comment: It overrides but calls the previous method I guess

Comment: Remember that you can always access the extended class by calling `super` in the subclass. Additionally your `ShipDecorator` constructor does not call the `SimpleShip` constructor. Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056097/java-extending-class-with-the-constructor-of-main-class-has-parameter

Comment: What I meant to ask was if my abstract class is okay - is it okay that I've overriden there all the methods (and not just those that I wanted to decorate)

Comment: @PhysicsPrincess My recommendation would be to put your code into an (online) IDE and make it run - after you have code that is compilable and executable you can think of the Decorator pattern again. It seems you are missing some concepts that you require to do it right in Java.

Comment: Sorry, I've reviewed my comment (the first comment) and it doesn't make sense, so I removed it. I do not agree with either of the two answers at the moment. The first one mimicked my concerns, which I've withdrawn, and the second call to the super method doesn't make sense to me. I do agree that just calling the other super methods explicitly doesn't make sense if it is done implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator pattern is supposed as you highlighted to add additional features to the ships as core feature are already existing in a basic ship. This `SimpleShip` always comes with those features.

Your vision of the decorator pattern is mostly correct but when you decorate the ship you have to keep core features as well as additional ones. It means that the `gotHit` should do what a `SimpleShip` do + additional things that `GuardedShip` do.

So, what that means in terms of code ?

You should call the orginal `gotHit()` before you do additional stuff in you decorated ships :

```
class SneakyShip<T extends Weapon> extends ShipDecorator<T>{
    public SneakyShip(SimpleShip<T> other, T weapon){
        super(other);
    }

    @Override
    private void gotHit(int reduction){
        super.gotHit(reduction); // core behaviour of every ship
        // additional feature of guarded ships
        if(new Random().nextDouble() > 0.25){
            // more damage
        }
    }
}
```

What you are doing in your code is completely changing the ship behaviour regarding the `gotHit` behaviour.

Here is some [references](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that it **must** override the methods of `SimpleShip`, if it does not actually do anything in the overridden method and it would be equal to

```
@Override
public void method() {
  super.method();
}
```

then you would just be generating more lines of code. If you want to decorate anything, then you are obviously required to override.

To reuse your example, although it is a bit odd:

```
class SneakyShip<T extends Weapon> extends ShipDecorator<T>{
    public SneakyShip(SimpleShip<T> other, T weapon){
        super(other);
    }

    // This is fine, it adds functionality.
    @Override
    private void gotHit(int reduction){
        super.gotHit(reduction); // You forgot to call the methods of the superclasses.
        if(new Random().nextDouble() > 0.25){
            simpleShip.gotHit(reduction);
        }
    }

    // This is unnecessary, because it is implicitly done.
    @Override
    public void attack(SpaceShip<?> other){
        super.attack(other);
    }
}
```

You would be required to if you were given a programming language that does not automatically call the overridden method without explicitly telling it to.

See the Design Patterns book by the Gang of Four for more information.

Comment: But I think that super.method() will not be helpful.. You need to use simpleShip.method().. to delegate the requests to the decorated object, or am I wrong?

Comment: You need to call the method of the superclass, so `super.method()` before you do any actual decoration, because you otherwise would ignore the result of all previous method calls. But if you do not add any functionality, then you don't have to override it. In your ship example, if you would add some function to paint the ship or something, you would not need to override the gotHit() method in this, lets say, PaintDecorator because you do not change the characteristics of the ship when it is hit (ignoring losing paint or being more hardened because of a layer of paint).

Comment: Is my abstract class okay? That's how it should be implemented?

Comment: If `SimpleShip other` should be the reference to the overridden `SimpleShip` instance, then no. You don't need to reference it explicitly, you can reference it by using `super`. Additionally you do not call the constructor of your superclass, `SimpleShip` in the `ShipDecorator`, you need to do this. See my comment on your question about this.